# expo run:androind ndk version cannot be changed

Tags: android, expo, android-ndk

Im running into an issue with Expo where repeatedly receiving the following error msg:

```
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
WARNING:C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
C/C++: Platform version '33' is beyond '31', the maximum API level supported by this NDK.
```

I already downoaded new SDK and NDK versions but still somehow my Expo project have this exact same error.
The generated Android folder and build.gradle file has the NDK of

```
    // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
```

I tried the same thing even in a new project and i received the same issue if i try to set the target API lvl to 33 (which is required by google now)

App.json content:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "experiment01",
    "slug": "experiment01",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
        "ExpoLocalization_supportsRTL": true
      },
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.anonymous.experiment01"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.anonymous.experiment01"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/en/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "minSdkVersion": 33,
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "33"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0",
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ],
      "expo-localization"
    ],
    "extra": {
      "supportsRTL": true
    },
    "locales": {
      "ja": "./i18n/ja/ja.json",
      "fi": "./i18n/fi/fi.json",
      "en": "./i18n/en/en.json",
      "hu": "./i18n/hu/hu.json"
    }
  }
}
```

And the dependencies im using are the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "expo": "^49.0.8",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "i18n-js": "^4.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
```

Im using managed workflow and would like to keep it that way. Any help appreciated.

****EDIT*****
IF i delete the old NDK version from android studio and let only the new ones, during npx expo run:android the ndk gets downloaded automatically....